# Some features to add in Android app to increase its functionality?

Tags: android, eclipse

I have a project on Android which is a basic Data Entry System. Data about fuel refilling in aviation industry for the employees can be entered, viewed and modified. I feel that this is a very basic app. Can you suggest some features that can be added in this app to increase its functionality. And as I am new to Android and I have very less time left to submit this project, some features that can very easily and with very less time be added to increase the functionality and its sample code or sites where I could refer to for the code would be greatly appreciated. 
PS: I have used Eclipse IDE.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is not programming related. It is design related. But to put light on your question, there is no point adding features for the sake of it. If it is not required to do something, then why add it? Sometimes simple and easy to use out weighs overcomplex for no reason.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about a specific programming question. It is about features to add to an app. This is something you would need to consult with your client, teacher, friends, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know much about aviation industry, but I have some general advices. **You should start thinking about problems users will be able to solve.**

Look at whole process of fuel refilling, maybe there are some problems, which are really a pain in the neck. For example, it is really hard to find good fuel transporter? Why not make functionality for searching transporting companies with prices, reviews, etc. Maybe there are some documents needs to be signed for fuel refilling, why not integrate with cloud sign service and give users ability to create and sign this documents in app?